# Need assistance with lua table containing multiple "rows"

Tags: json, lua

I am pulling a result from an outside source via json and using a json library to convert it to a table. The results can be multiple rows, which is what I am having difficulty figuring out. I am using a software platform with lua as the backend. I have the json library from Jeffrey Friedl from here: [JSON Decode](http://regex.info/blog/lua/json)

Example of table data returned from the json:decode library that is included in the platform I am using:
'{"THE_TYPE":"M","P_TYPE":"L","CODESET_DESCRIPTION":"X","CODESET_ID":356,"ErrorMessage":"","S_AMOUNT":2562.5,"T_AMOUNT":4200},{"THE_TYPE":"M","P_TYPE":"A","CODESET_DESCRIPTION":"All Codes","CODESET_ID":359,"ErrorMessage":"","S_AMOUNT":0,"T_AMOUNT":2500}'

I have tried several iterations of pairs and ipairs and just can't seem to get my code to differentiate between rows.

This gives me the first row of data:

```lua
local data = json:decode(result.data.http.get) --example only to clarify how data is converted into lua table 
for k, v in pairs(data) do
   print(k, v)
end
```

I have also tried variations on calling the table via row number, but my understanding of tables in lua isn't spectacular.

```lua
for k, v in pairs(data[1]) do
```

or

```lua
for k, v in ipairs(data[1]) do
```

but those return errors stating it expected a table but got nil

I'd like to be able to parse this row by row, doesn't even need to be in a specific returned order, I just need the data so I can work with it.

Comment: What library are you using for parsing json? When are you parsing it? Code sample you have provided is missing json parsing part and will fail due to passing a string to `pairs`.

Comment: @Green, My code is a little oversimplified. I am working inside of a platform that uses lua as a basis for coding. The json library they are using is from Jeffrey Friedl http://regex.info/blog/lua/json

I see now that my string method to show the data isn't valid for this code example.

basically I get the data into a local variable:
```lua
result = http.post results
local data = json:decode(result) --gives me a lua table of the data
```

Comment: @Green I have updated my initial question to clarify, hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Try `for k, v in ipairs(JSON:decode('['..your_json_as_text..']')) do ... end`

Comment: well, that gives me a list of tables now. So that is a start. I think I can enumerate through those in my do statement.

1       table: 0x418c6e80
2       table: 0x418c6ec8

Answer (score 0):

first, use `json.decode` with dot, 
and secondly, the json text should be checked for validity :

```
local  s = [[
[
  {
    "THE_TYPE": "M",
    "P_TYPE": "L",
    "CODESET_DESCRIPTION": "X",
    "CODESET_ID": 356,
    "ErrorMessage": "",
    "S_AMOUNT": 2562.5,
    "T_AMOUNT": 4200
  },
  {
    "THE_TYPE": "M",
    "P_TYPE": "A",
    "CODESET_DESCRIPTION": "All Codes",
    "CODESET_ID": 359,
    "ErrorMessage": "",
    "S_AMOUNT": 0,
    "T_AMOUNT": 2500
  }
]
]]


local data = json.decode(s) 
print(data)
for k, v in pairs(data[1]) do
   print(k, v)
end
```